# should base case always be the front of mathematical induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

For both strong and common induction, $K + 1$ seems not rely on base case(s), just needs $K$ be true,

However, if base cases are not true, the induction below are meaningless.

so can I put base case anywhere, just before the conclusion(e.g. So, the statement holds true!)

Comment: @DavidK thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I just happened to remember seeing the other question recently, which is fortunate since I don't know how one would find it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the steps in either order. As long as you prove both the base and the inductive case, the proof is complete. It simply is more intuitive to do the base case first. There are however cases where it is best to prove the base case first.

Example: A generalization of Euclid's Lemma:

$p|a_1a_2...a_n\Rightarrow(p|a_1\lor p|a_2\lor...\lor p|a_n),\qquad p\text{ prime}$

To prove this, you first have to prove the base case, that if $p|ab$, then $p|a$ or $p|b$.Then say it holds true for a product of $n$ numbers. Group a product of $n+1$ numbers as $(a_1a_2...a_n)a_{n+1}$ and apply the base case to this product. Together with the inductive assumption, this completes the inductive step.